# Aniqroid SlidingTray NullRefferenceException?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to use [SlidingTray](http://code.google.com/p/aniqroid/).
But adding the example into my view it gives `NullPointerException` in `SlidingTray.onLayout()`.

Testing on Android 4.1.

Stack:

```
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at com.sileria.android.view.SlidingTray.onLayout(Unknown Source)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4571)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4571)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4571)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4571)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4571)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4571)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1665)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2700)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
09-29 01:31:06.840: E/AndroidRuntime(8905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
```

Any ideas why I am seeing this exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using this library for a while now, and got stuck with this same error. Since i turned the project into an android library project instead of just using the jar, i was able to detect where was the error.

On line 455 there is `switch (mHandlePos) {` here is the nullpointer.

Looking on the code, there's a setter for this mHandlePos, so all i did was calling this setter and i was good to go. Check it out:

```
FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.historico_main, null);
    ImageView handler = new Tools(this).newImage(R.drawable.historico_handler);

    SlidingTray historico = new SlidingTray(this, handler, content, SlidingTray.TOP);

    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main_parent);
    historico.setHandlePosition(Side.TOP);
    parent.addView(historico, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

I think the developer forgot to set the default position of the handler in the constructor. Well, calling the `setHandlePosition` worked for me without having to change the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I used this library, I got also same error. There is a public method

```
slidingTray.setHandlePosition(Side side);
```

just call this function and pass your side as

```
slidingTray.setHandlePosition(Side.BOTTOM);
```

then It will work.

But I have an issue, I didn't work on sliding, I don't know why...:-(

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry guys for this error. I have fixed the problem in the new release 3.5 which is available directly from my website: http://aniqroid.sileria.com

Thank you for using the library, and feel free to report bugs.